# ¿Cómo hacer operaciones con dos campos calculados?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando obtener un calculo de eficiencia por usuarios.
Verán, tengo una consulta en la que obtengo los resultados de las consultas que han sido resueltas y las que no, quiero obtener la eficiencia por parte del usuario operando (Resueltas/totalConsultas)*100 pero no logro el resultado deseado, solo me hace la operación para un registro y me lo replica para los demás

la consulta es la siguiente:

(la columna "conteo" representa el total de consultas hechas por el usuario y registro si las que fueron resueltas)

```
select 
NombreUsuario,Item_Consulta,count(1) as Conteo,
SUM(CASE WHEN Estado = 'Resuelto'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS 'RegistroSi', 
SUM(CASE WHEN Estado = 'No Resuelto' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS 'RegistroNO' 
from Reg_Consulta_cafe  
group by NombreUsuario,Item_Consulta
```

[image: aca muestro el resultado esperado]

Comment: O sea que esa imagen no es lo que arroja la consulta? Qué estás obteniendo y sobre qué datos podemos probar esa consulta?

Comment: si lo siento, enrealidad es un excel, donde solo pegue el resultado arrojado, pero sin ahcer el calciulo de la eficiencia, pero la columna final es decir la de eficiencia, eso es lo que yo quiero obtener..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos formas, puedes usar una subconsulta, para poder usar los nuevos nombres de columna:

```
select NombreUsuario,
       Item_Consulta,
       Conteo,
       RegistroSi,
       RegistroNo,
       (RegistroSi / (Conteo * 1.0) ) * 100 AS 'Eficiencia'
       from (select NombreUsuario,
                    Item_Consulta,
                    count(1) as Conteo,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Estado = 'Resuelto'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS 'RegistroSi', 
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Estado = 'No Resuelto' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'RegistroNO' 
                    from Reg_Consulta_cafe  
                    group by NombreUsuario,Item_Consulta
              ) T
```

O simplemente en tu consulta repites el calculo, es decir:

```
(SUM(CASE WHEN Estado = 'Resuelto'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(1)) * 100 as 'Eficiencia'
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por contestar, probe ese codigo y no me funciono, ya habia probado de unas maneras similares pero tampoco habia funcionado pero obtenia el mismo resulatdos..

Comment: basicamente obtuve que en unas celdas me tiraba 100 y en otras 0

Comment: Si, al tratarse siempre de valores enteros, el resultado final es un entero. Chequea mi última edición.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: ya lo logre resolver con esa modificacion